# PHP script for Mailchimp webhooks

Tags: php, mailchimp

I'm working with mailchimp API where i'm interested in two features in the API:

(i) synching my database with mailchimp (https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/how-to/sync-you-to-mailchimp.php) - SUCCESSFULLY DONE

(ii) synching mailchimp with my database (https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/how-to/sync-mailchimp-to-you.php) - STUCK HERE

Mailchimp have a feature called **webhooks** which has been a pain for me to learn and understand.

They give the sample code below to show how one can go about it but it's really not clear

```
<?php
/***********************************************
Sample code for handling MailChimp Webhooks - to write the logfile, your webserver must be able to write 
to the file in the wh_log() function below.

This also assumes you use a key to secure the script and configure a URL like this in MailChimp:


***********************************************/
$my_key  = 'EnterAKey!';

wh_log('==================[ Incoming Request ]==================');

wh_log("Full _REQUEST dump:\n".print_r($_REQUEST,true)); 

if ( !isset($_GET['key']) ){
    wh_log('No security key specified, ignoring request'); 
} elseif ($_GET['key'] != $my_key) {
    wh_log('Security key specified, but not correct:');
    wh_log("\t".'Wanted: "'.$my_key.'", but received "'.$_GET['key'].'"');
} else {
    //process the request
    wh_log('Processing a "'.$_POST['type'].'" request...');
    switch($_POST['type']){
        case 'subscribe'  : subscribe($_POST['data']);   break;
        case 'unsubscribe': unsubscribe($_POST['data']); break;
        case 'cleaned'    : cleaned($_POST['data']);     break;
        case 'upemail'    : upemail($_POST['data']);     break;
        case 'profile'    : profile($_POST['data']);     break;
        default:
            wh_log('Request type "'.$_POST['type'].'" unknown, ignoring.');
    }
}
wh_log('Finished processing request.');

/***********************************************
    Helper Functions
***********************************************/
function wh_log($msg){
    $logfile = 'webhook.log';
    file_put_contents($logfile,date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." | ".$msg."\n",FILE_APPEND);
}

function subscribe($data){
    wh_log($data['email'] . ' just subscribed!');
}
function unsubscribe($data){
    wh_log($data['email'] . ' just unsubscribed!');
}
function cleaned($data){
    wh_log($data['email'] . ' was cleaned from your list!');
}
function upemail($data){
    wh_log($data['old_email'] . ' changed their email address to '. $data['new_email']. '!');
}
function profile($data){
    wh_log($data['email'] . ' updated their profile!');
}
```

I kindly need assistance on how to go about configuring a PHP webhook script that will allow me to sync real time updates from my mailchimp list to my database

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? You essentially just need to fill in the blanks in the above code, in the `subscribe` etc. functions.

Comment: would you mind explaining whats happening in the code?..i genuinely have no clue.

Comment: Do you understand how *"normal"* PHP scripts work? What's happening when you open `localhost/foobar.php` in your browser? Do you understand GET and POST?

Comment: yes i do..my issue is that the above sample code is not clear..i'm not sure what they mean when they say '$my_key  = 'EnterAKey!';'..which key is this??

Comment: The comment hints that you should configure the URL with this secret key in the Mailchimp settings, e.g. just add `?key=jskejsindjsbnfks` to the URL. The purpose being that you can verify who the request comes from and not allow random strangers to call this URL. Any other specific concerns?

Comment: you're right sir.thankyou..the key is the api key